# jQuery selector of name attribute for different element types

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table of rows.  In one of the columns, some rows have a span with static text, some rows have a select with values to choose from.  All elements in that one column have the same name attribute.  In my form submit, I iterate thru the rows and want to get the values for all columns.  I would prefer to have one jQuery selector statement to get the value from that element (span or select with name attribute of "materialValue").  How would I do that with jQuery?  Here follows the html snippet.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
      <span id="materialValue1" name="materialValue>ONE</span>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
      <span id="materialValue2" name="materialValue>TWO</span>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
      <select id="materialValue3" name="materialValue>
        <option>ONE</option>
        <option>TWO</option>
        <option>THREE</option>
      </select>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
      <select id="materialValue4" name="materialValue>
        <option>ONE</option>
        <option>TWO</option>
        <option>THREE</option>
      </select>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Edit: I'm used to specifying the element type then square brackets with the attribute name/value.  I'm not sure how to specify the jquery selector without the element type name.  e.g. `$('span[name="materialValue"]', this)`.  Is it legal to specify `$('[name="materialValue"]', this)`?  looks weird to me.

Comment: Create the selector based on `name=materialValue`

Comment: [As Andrew says](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: using same `name` attribute is invalid markup. either use `name = whatever[]`

Comment: @diEcho, why would using the same `name` on multiple elements be invalid? Thats how check boxes and radio buttons work in the first place.

Comment: there are different element `span` `div` `select` with same name. 'checkbox' 'radio` have diffrent property

Comment: @diEcho, I understand, but it only means that multiple values will be available for the same name in server-side code. Using a `[]` suffix is a PHP idiom that allows to access these values in an array. Other languages do not have any problem letting you do that without tweaking the `name` attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is an attribute selector:

```
$("[name='MaterialValue']")
```

Also, you are missing closing quotes after your attribute `name` in your html

Look here for reference:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: To answer the question edit: it looks weird, but it's perfectly fine. In fact, it's just like how you already use `#id` or `.class` without a type or `*` selector in your everyday code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I just wasn't sure on how it would work with an attribute selector. Learn something new everyday...

Answer (score 4):

Like this...

```
$("[name=materialValue]")    // Select element with name attribute with a specific value
```

Attributes are selected using brackets. You can also use it like this in other cases...

```
$("div[id]")      // Select element with an id attribute

$("[name*=test]") // Select all elements with *test* in the name attribute (partial)
```

etc..